# Why does apt-get remove only a few kB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I installed nginx (`sudo apt-get install nginx`) and then removed it with `sudo apt-get remove nginx`. I to need ensure that the application is uninstalled and cannot run.
(I'm still able to run `service nginx start` without error in `nginx\error.log`).

I wonder why only 90kB was removed when I downloaded several megabytes? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `apt-get purge nginx`.

Comment: Check the description of the `nginx` package, which says: "This is a dependency package to install either nginx-full (by default) or nginx-light."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i wonder why only 90kB was removed when i downloaded many MB ?

This 90kb might only be the `nginx` executable. You can remove configuration files and other files left behind by the program with `apt-get purge <program_name>`.

The other MBs you might have downloaded were programs on which nginx might depend on to execute (so called dependencies). To remove dependencies with apt run `apt-get autoremove`

For a more canonical answer, consider this:

- `apt-get remove <package_name>` will **remove the binary files**, but **not** data or configuration files.
- `apt-get purge <package_name>` will **remove everything that  has installed**, but **not** its dependencies. *This might be useful in case you want to reinstall a piece of software*, due to, for example, messed up configurations. You can also do the same thing if you run `apt-get remove --purge <package_name>`
- `apt-get autoremove` removes software that was installed as a dependency by some other software, but are no longer needed.

Comment: okay thank you, i did all this command but configuration files are still in /etc/nginx and i can run nginx service and connect to website.. when i manually delete /etc/nginx and run 'apt-get install nginx' the configuration files are not created.. i really dont understand this .. `apt-get purge nginx` or `apt-get remove --purge nginx` also delete 90kB.. `apt-get autoremove` does nothing (0 to remove).. wtf :P and nginx is still running !! it was clean ubuntu installation by me so im sure i have no other webserver running

Comment: maybe uninstallation was done but service process was still running, now im rebooting machine and will tell.. okay nginx is NOT uninstalled and still running (if i copy confs to /etc/nginx).. i really need to uninstall this :P

Comment: @Scott Dit it work?

Comment: okay `apt-get purge nginx nginx-common nginx-full` seems to really uninstalled the nginx service with all confs and binary